# Query lucene index against IEnumerable field

Tags: c#, linq, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore8

I have a set of courses in a Lucene index, which contain zero or more available dates. I am trying to query the index so that any courses with an available date falling between a From/To date are returned.

The field is being brought back as a collection of DateTime objects using the property within my CourseSearchResultItem

```
 public class CourseSearchResultItem : SearchResultItem
 {
     [IndexField("availabledatesforcourse")]
     public IEnumerable<DateTime> AvailableDatesForCourse { get; set;}
 }
```

The query that is being constructed uses the following code:

```
 if (courseSearchCriteria.FromDate.HasValue)
     query = query.Where(c => c.AvailableDatesForCourse.Any(d => d >= courseSearchCriteria.FromDate.Value));

 if (courseSearchCriteria.ToDate.HasValue)
     query = query.Where(c => c.AvailableDatesForCourse.Any(d => d <= courseSearchCriteria.ToDate.Value));
```

Running this produces the following exception:

> Unsupported lambda in Any call. Expression used 'd => (d >= Value (RCS.Web.Areas.RcsEng.Controllers.CoursesApiController +<>c__DisplayClass10_0).courseSearchCriteria.FromDate.Value)'

I know that this is a result of limitations of the Sitecore.Linq Any() method, but am unsure how to recreate the desired functionality. Has anybody had a similar issue that can shed some light on a solution?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I don't think you can do subqueries in Sitecore search.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following.

Change your class to look like this:

```
 public class CourseSearchResultItem : SearchResultItem
 {
     [IgnoreIndexFieldAttribute]
     [IndexField("availabledatesforcourse")]
     public DateTime AvailableDatesForCourse { get; set;}
 }
```

Now change your query to look like this:

```
if (courseSearchCriteria.FromDate.HasValue)
     query = query.Where(c => c.AvailableDatesForCourse == courseSearchCriteria.FromDate.Value);

if (courseSearchCriteria.ToDate.HasValue)
 query = query.Where(c => c.AvailableDatesForCourse == courseSearchCriteria.ToDate.Value));
```

This sort of syntax works for values that are stored multiple times in a search document (for example, the _path field, which stores the GUIDs of all the parent items separately).  It will be translated by the ContentSearch API into a query
that Lucene can understand, something like this:

```
AvailableDatesForCourse:<your date>
```

**Update** The `[IgnoreIndexFieldAttribute]` will prevent a mapping error when ContentSearch hydrates your class, but will not prevent the field from being used in a query. I wrote a LinqScratchPad [Gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dsolovay/4d377695354e06194710/raw/70dfadfa2fef4a1061ede8fa921af8c6e1f36079/SearchOnUnmappedField.cs) to illustrate this, which you can load in the Sitecore LinqScratchPad at /sitecore/admin/LinqScratchPad.aspx, either by pasting it in or using the URL Fetch button. This finds all items that have "Media Item" in the name:

[image: LinqScratchPad example]

Comment: Thank Dan, the query now returns the courses with an available date between the From and To dates, however, when trying to map the object back from the search results into the CourseSearchResultItem class, it appears to be trying to map a string array into a single string object.

This results in the following:

**Could not map index document field to property "AvailableDateForCourse" on type CourseSearchResultItem : Could not convert value of type System.String[] to destination type System.DateTime: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.String'.**

Comment: Updated answer with discussion of IgnoreFieldAttribute, which should get you around this issue.

Comment: Hi Dan, using the IgnoreIndexField (sitecore 8 version) to prevent the mapping back of the available dates worked a treat. Thanks for your help - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and followed Dan's steps which got me part of the way to a solution. The issue I was having was that SitecoreContentSearch was creating a query that Solr couldn't parse. I updated the linq query to this:

```
if (courseSearchCriteria.FromDate.HasValue && courseSearchCriteria.ToDate.HasValue)
query= query.Where(x => x.AvailableDatesForCourse.Between(courseSearchCriteria.FromDate.Value,courseSearchCriteria.ToDate.Value,Inclusion.Both));
```

This should create a query that looks like this :

```
availabledatesforcourse:[2018-07-13T15:48:42.975Z TO 2021-07-13T15:48:43.023Z]
```

This allows me to search a list of dates for any value that falls into this range.